# Suggested Edit of link only answer

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-edit

[Rejected Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15250942) which has me confused.  I found an answer that had only a link as an answer.  So I went to the link and pulled out some actual that I think might be useful if the link ever went away.

All three reviewers marked it as:

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.

I guess I'm looking for a little insight into whether my edit was really that bad or not?

Comment: "Contact your administrator" is the exact same kind of solution as "click here to solve your problem".  Not a solution, programmers don't like to contact anybody and they don't like to click a link.   Some answers just *need* to be a link, not well understood by reviewers.  But a very, very strong hint that this mishap was caused by the question.  Always look there next, high odds it wasn't researched at all.  And doesn't have anything to do with programming.

Comment: A rejection code more in line with that would have made more sense to me.

Comment: "no improvement whatsoever" would have been a better reject reason, yes. Maybe the first person mis-clicked (the two are adjacent) and the rest of the reviewers just jumped on the band wagon. But the particular reason isn't really important - they don't have different implications.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how that's a *useful answer to the question* **at all**. The question seems to be asking where to get the username and password info, not how to put it on the command line. The reviewers were right to reject it.

Comment: password password Specify the password for the Changepoint account. **If you do not know the password, contact your Changepoint administrator.** Passwords are entered in plain text in your shell or calling script, but are encrypted in all further network traffic.  Which I still think is better then pointing to just PDF.

Comment: Looks like the whole answer was now deleted so I guess the better option was to flag instead of editing.

Comment: In an absolute sense, yes, the revision is *slightly* better than the original. But it's not better *enough* to justify spending reviewer time and bumping the question to the homepage.

Answer (score 2):

We can't really know why they rejected it as spam/vandalism. Maybe they mistook the edit as an audit, or maybe they didn't try to decipher the text and thought it was some random gibberish.

And I can see why, primarily because it lacks any formatting and it has repeated words in it:

> -password password Specify the password for the Changepoint ...

If you look at that first line, it doesn't start with proper English, but with repeated words. Further the word "password" is all over the place, which makes it look spammy.

You probably should have formatted it like this:

> `-password <password>` 
>   Specify the password for the Changepoint ...

---

Then again, I can't really see what this adds to the answer in regard to what was asked in the first place. But that would be another rejection reason.

Comment: I thought it might be a little better then just a link.  But it appears that deleting the answer is where it is now.  So I guess next time I should just flag it.